# Hibernate Linux on ARM

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, hibernation

I am working to implement hibernation (Suspend to disk) on ARM and have successfully done that by using [swsusp ARM patch by Sebastian Capella](https://lists.linaro.org/pipermail/linaro-kernel/2014-March/012112.html).  Now I can hibernate (suspend to swap partition in *sd* card) the kernel using the command `echo disk > /sys/power/state` and the system will resume its state with the next power on.  But if I press reset again the kernel follow a normal boot sequence.

My question is how can I make that swap area and hibernate image in that area permanent, so that in every reset it will awake from that permanent image?  I have given the value of `swapiness=0` so that I expect there wont be any swapping of pages any more while system is alive.  How kernel decide whether go for a normal boot or awake from (`resume=/dev/swap_partition`) hibernation?

I searched a lot on internet but didn't get a clear idea about how Linux kernel is awaking from hibernation and what it will do with swap after resuming once.Thank you for your time

My kernel version is 3.14

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code trace of Linux Hibernation APIs calls:

http://www.srcmap.org/sd_share/4/839d1dea/Linux_kernel_Hibernation_Resume.html

Most of the code trace is for PowerPC.  But it might give you some idea on  the kernel restore-from-hibernation flow.

For ARM, maybe you need to:

- On hibernation, just marks the permanent swap file as the swap file.
- On resume, prevents the system to "unmarks" that swap file as hibernation file.
- Be very careful about kernel image upgrade, the swap file contents are tightly couple to the kernel image.  Any minor chg/recompile in kernel will mark the swap file invalid and trigger a reboot action .   Add a lot of printk() logs for this.